# My fetch is failing to pull a JSON file that is in the same directory as it

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I'm trying to pull a JSON file into my code. It is in the same directory as the file I'm trying to pul it into so it is not an issue with the file path from what I see. This is the error I get...

> VM45:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Coding() {
    const [Coding, setCoding] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch('./Objects.json')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.json())
                return result.json();
            })
            .then((pop) => {
                console.log('Coding')
                setCoding(pop);
                console.log(Coding)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }, [])


    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "title": "Example",
        "content": "lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssss"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "title": "Example",
        "content": "lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssss"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "title": "Example",
        "content": "lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssss"
    },
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "title": "Example",
        "content": "lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssss"
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "title": "Example",
        "content": "lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssss"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is returned instead? Are you sure the file is served under the given URL? (Check network tab.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that relative URLs may not give you the desired result if you use client-side routing... For instance, `./Object.json` fetched from the website `https://example.com/some/route/here` will go to `https://example.com/some/route/Object.json` - it would make more sense to specify root-relative URLs here.

Comment: The JSON file is stored locally, it is in the same folder. Not hosted on the internet.

Comment: Then how do you expect it to be loaded from a website with `fetch` at runtime? Maybe you want to include it at compile-time?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a local JSON file, there's no need to fetch it. You can simply `require` it:

```
const objects = require('./Objects.json');
React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log('Coding')
     setCoding(objects);
     console.log(Coding)
}, [])
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it is not logging the code in a way that I can extract the JSON information. My goal is to convert the JSON objects into regular objects

Comment: I also plan on having this eventually be a call to a database once I learn databases.  Thank you so much for your help.